# Homestead Directory Missing After Reboot VM or Computer

Tags: macos, laravel, vagrant, laravel-5, homestead

**Homestead.yaml**

```
folders:
    - map: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code
      to:  /home/vagrant/code
```

---

- Local directory : /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/**code**
- Homestead directory : /home/vagrant/**code**

---

Everything is working perfectly beofore I reboot my computer, my homestead directory doesn't seem to sync with my local one anymore. They're **missing** completely.

- I start my `homestead` `VM` , and `SSH` into it.
- Then, I  go into `~/code`, and nothing there.

---

I tried to research into it, but [people](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/homestead-shared-folders-empty-on-reboot?page=1) seem to have the same issue.

What is going on here ?
How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my local homestead directory, I run `vagrant reload`, I got this

[image]

and it works 100% for me.

---

**vagrant reload** : restarts vagrant machine, loads new Vagrantfile.

Answer (score 0):

in your terminal Change directory to where your Homestead file was created
and type "VAGRANT UP" lower case.

well it work for me